# Let a function wait for response - Swift

Tags: swift, response, wait, adventure

Im trying to programm a text adventure. I have a NSTextView in which the user can write commands and get a response but I can't find a way to "pause" a function to wait for the users response.

```
import Cocoa

@IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!

var playerName:String = ""
var enteredString:String = ""

//Keyboard Input

private func returnChar(theEvent: NSEvent) -> Character?{
    let s: String = theEvent.characters!
    for char in s{
        return char
    }
    return nil
}

override func keyUp (theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let s: String = String(self.returnChar(theEvent)!)
    enteredString.extend(s)

    if theEvent.keyCode == 36 {

        //Here I'd like to 
        //say that start() 
        //should continue

    }
}

//Story

func start() {
    textView.string?.extend("Hi, what's your name?\n")

    //Here I'd like to 
    //wait for the
    //users response

    playerName = enteredString
    textView.string?.extend("Are you sure that I should call you \(playerName)")

}
```

Thanks for your reply :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Swift 2 you can use readLine() that waits until the user presses enter in the command line. And it returns String? because the user can hit enter without having typed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that waiting for input in a `NSTextView` isn't a good strategy.

What if you have a method that knows what state your app is in?  Then whenever you get text you want to use, send it to that method and let it decide, based on state, how to use it (a name, a command...).  Meanwhile, your app has just returned to the run loop, letting the user do what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Add the UITextField delegate and an UITextField for user input. Set the UITextField delegate to self and add the method: 'textFieldShouldReturn'.

In this method handle the logic whenever an user has entered stuff.
Here is a short snippet:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var userInputTextField: UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userInputTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, view.frame.width, 100))
        userInputTextField?.delegate = self
        userInputTextField?.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
        view.addSubview(userInputTextField!)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        println(textField.text)
        return true
    }
}
```